# Calculating gas cost of a transaction on-chain

Tags: contract-design, gas

We can read the gas limit and the gas price of a current TX in solidity. However, reading those values already uses some of the gas.

What is a reliable way to calculate the actual gas cost of a transaction? An example would be that a whitelisted address has to pay an user, but the gas costs have to be subtracted from this payment.